# Linux Error Installing Package

Tags: linux, unix

I encounter error during packages in linux server.

Eg:

```
root@S41BF069 install_rpm]# rpm -Uvh unixODBC-2.2.14-12.el6_3.i686.rpm
warning: unixODBC-2.2.14-12.el6_3.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:unixODBC               ########################################### [100%]
error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: read failed - Bad file descriptor
[root@S41BF069 install_rpm]#
```

Any idea??

Comment: What version of Linux are you attempting to install this RPM on? (Distribution / version number)

Comment: Ok, is there a reason you're trying to install a 32 bit (i686) package, instead of the 64 (x86_64) bit package?

Comment: From the Oracle EBS Installation Notes, state that is required to have this package before can proceed with the other installation.

Comment: Does it specify architecture? If you're on a 64 bit distribution, you should really be using 64 bit packages.

Comment: hmm ok noted. But is there any possible that the file corrupt?

Comment: I guess it's possible..try verifying it.. http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-verify.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to the fact that you are trying to install a 32 bit (i686) package on a 64 bit (x86_64) distribution.

Download the x86_64 package from [here](http://pkgs.org/centos-6/centos-x86_64/unixODBC-2.2.14-12.el6_3.x86_64.rpm/download/), and see if that helps at all.